# Help to construct a State space model of a unipolar stepper motor with shorted phases

Tags: stepper-motor, state-space

I hope to get some help on an interesting task - I cannot seem to get my model to work which is my I ask for help here.

I am trying to construct a model of the unipolar stepper (seen below in the figure). I was hoping to get a model of what would happen if I try to drive a unipolar stepper with a bipolar driver (which is why the "fifth" wire is not modelled as it would be "open"). The unipolar steppers can have a short between phase A and B which I have modelled below. The problem is that my model won't run or is unstable.

I have tried with the "normal" state-space formulation:
M x' = Ax + Bu, where:

A1 = [-R1-R2 R2          0       R1;
R2     -R2-R3-R5    R3      R5;
0      R3          -R3-R4   R4;
R1     R5           R4      -R4-R5-R1]

M=[L1+L2    -L2     0   -L1;
-L2      L2+L3   -L3  0;
0        -L3     L3+L4 -L4
-L1      0       -L4     L4+L1]

inv(M)*A;

B1 = [1 -1 0 0;
0 1 -1 0;
0 0 1 -1;
-1 0 0 1]

x' = inv(M) A x + inv(M)Bu

D = 0
C = [1 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0;
0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 1]

All inductances were just randomly chosen to 0.01H and the resistance are 50 ohm. Disregard the "e" for back-emf as that will be added as an input later.

Why is my model then unstable, any tips or tricks?

Thank you.

[image]